# How can I attach listeners to a service without modifying the service factory for each listener?

Tags: dependencies, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I have a very simple class that I've put inside module `Mail`'s service configuration.

```
'factories' => array(
    'mailer' => function (ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
        return new \Project\Mail\Mailer();
    }
)
```

Now, `Mailer` uses the `EventManager` to trigger events. I'd like to attach a listener class that will log an error whenever `Mailer` failed sending an email, but I'd like to do so *without* modifying `Mailer` every time I have a new listener to attach.

How can I setup the `Mailer` class so that listeners can be attached from other modules?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to identify first what you mean by "`Mailer` fails sending an email". If you can check for this condition within your `Mailer` class you must then trigger a corresponding `mail.error` or similar event.

Then you have to attach a listener to the `EventManager` inside of the `Mailer` to listen for this `mail.error` event and log the error.

### Triggering error within `Mailer`

Let's assume our `Mailer` class looks something like this:

```php
<?php
namespace Project\Mail;

class Mailer
{
    const EVENT_MAIL_ERROR = 'mail.error';

    protected $events;

    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $this->events = $events;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if ($this->events === null)
        {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager);
        }
        return $this->events;
    }

    public function send(MessageInterface $msg)
    {
        // try sending the message. uh-oh we failed!
        if ($someErrorCondition)
        {
            $this->getEventManager()->trigger(self::EVENT_MAIL_ERROR, $this, array(
                'custom-param' => 'failure reason',
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

### Listening for the event

During bootstrap we attach listener(s) to the `EventManager` within `Mailer`.

```php
<?php
namespace FooBar;

use Zend\EventManager\Event;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $services = $application->getServiceManager();
        $mailer = $services->get('Mailer');

        $mailer->getEventManager()->attach(Mailer::EVENT_MAIL_ERROR, function(Event $event)
        {
            $param = $event->getParam('custom-param');
            // log the error
        });
    }
}
```

Please refer to the documentation on [EventManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) for implementation details.

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to setup anything in the class triggering events, you just need to listen to them.

Although @user2257808's answer works, it's not the most efficient way to do it, since the act of fetching the mailer from the service manager creates an instance, even if one isn't needed in the rest of the application.

The better approach is to attach your listeners to the shared event manager, which will be notified if an event is triggered.

To do that is very similar to the other answer

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $sharedEvents = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    // listen to the 'someMailEvent' when triggered by the mailer
    $sharedEvents->attach('Project\Mail\Mailer', 'someMailEvent', function($e) {
         // do something for someMailEvent
    });
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about the mailer even being available, but if it is, and it triggers an event your listener will pick it up.